# Whats the best way to start building an application that should work on windows 8 tablet

Tags: eclipse, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-7

**Background:**

I have to build a Windows 8 application using HTML5 and Javascript. The application should work on windows 8 tablets and should do authentication using the windows provided native javascript Apis.

**Issue:**

I have a windows 7 laptop. I am coming from Java background and don't know about the windows side much.

**Question:**

I have done research , but got really confused

If I have to build my Windows 8 tablet specific application then what is the best option.

1. Should I install Visual studio into my laptop and then start
   building the  windows 8 application? ..
2. If I am going to use visual studio then which version should I use
   as my laptop is running windows 7 ?
3. Or should I get my java eclipse IDE and install some additional
   plugins to start building my windows 8 specific application ?...If
   yes then which plugin should i use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first of all, there isn't any way to create windows 8 app in windows 7 PC (except you run windows 8 on a separate virtual machine). Check [this](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/getstarted) for more info.
- Yes, you have to install visual studio for Windows 8 app development anyway.
- Visual Studio 2013 is a better choice to start with which includes most of all that you're gonna need.
- For other tools check [this](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/downloads).
- There isn't any way to install any plugin into Eclipse and start developing apps for windows. You can only write scripts and html in Eclipse but App specific configuration, you have to do it in Visual Studio.

But my question to you is that why would you like to make Windows 8 App when you can make a Universal (Windows 10) app by spending same amount of time and efforts..! see the future. Windows 8 is not gonna last longer than a year (approx announcement in Build2015). Though No doubt, apps made for windows 8 will work on Windows 10 also with some exceptions.

Hope this helps..!
All the best...